# Ubuntu 18.04 - display settings lost after reboot

Tags: 18.04, display, nvidia-settings

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and the newest nvidia drivers - 440. I use 3 monitors. I run nvidia-settings to set monitors layouts. After reboot the settings are lost. I have found this thread with possible solution: [Display settings lost on reboot on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031248/display-settings-lost-on-reboot-on-ubuntu-18-04) but I wonder if there is any other way to fix it without setting monitor layout during every startup ? What causes that problem ? Is it any known bug ?

Comment: You could add the command script to the startup applications to apply the Nvidia settings at every login.